# How to determine whether a git pull did something from a shell script

Tags: git, shell

I run a script on login that opens a terminal and runs a shell script in it that reads

```
git pull --rebase && git log
```

However, this git log will run even if there were no changes upstream. How can I modify this script to only run the `git log` if there were changes?

Comment: you must be really trusting to blindly run a git pull on login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
prev=$(git rev-list HEAD -n 1)
git pull --rebase
test $prev = $(git rev-list HEAD -n 1) || git log
```

Answer (score 3):

A "regular" (no `--rebase`) `git pull` really runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  A `git pull --rebase` really runs `git fetch` followed by `git rebase` (with some cleverness in case the "tracking branch" you're rebasing onto was itself rebased).

In both cases, it's actually the `fetch` step that brings in upstream changes.  The second part (merge or rebase) simply combines those upstream changes, if any, with your changes, if any.  So what you want to find out is: was anything fetched from the upstream tracking branch?

[janos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995691/1256452) will work just fine.  To understand *why*, though, consider the way the commit graph looks before and after the `git pull --rebase`.  We'll start with a simple graph with just commits `A`, `B`, and `Y`, where `A` and `B` are "on" the upstream branch and `Y` is your own commit that will be rebased:

```
A - B          <-- origin/master
      \
        Y      <-- HEAD=master
```

(this assumes that you're on branch `master` and your remote is named `origin`, but since we only look at `HEAD` it works for any branch and any remote).

If the `fetch` step does nothing, this diagram remains the same after the (no-op/skipped) merge-or-rebase step.  So `HEAD` is still `master` which still refers to commit `Y` (`Y` stands for one of those long SHA-1 strings like `43be6d8...`; these are the "true names" of commits, and they never change; you can't change a commit, you can only stop looking at it, as we'll see below).

If the `fetch` step brings in a new commit `C`, though, the intermediate diagram looks like this:

```
A - B - C      <-- origin/master
      \
        Y      <-- HEAD=master
```

Now `git pull --rebase` has to run `git rebase` to copy commit your `Y` to a new commit.  The existing `Y` commit remains in there, but the label, `master`, is moved to point to the new commit.  Let's call the new commit `Y'` since its contents are basically the same as those of `Y`, it's just the parent-ID is now `C` instead of `B`.  So now you have:

```
A - B - C      <-- origin/master
     .    \
      .     Y' <-- HEAD=master
       .
        Y          [no label - abandoned]
```

So, let's take that short script and simplify it slightly (and I'll reverse the test even though that makes it a little longer, and add double quotes):

```
prev=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
git pull --rebase
test "$prev" != "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" && git log
```

The first `rev-parse` finds the SHA-1 for your `HEAD` commit (`Y`).  Then we do the `git pull --rebase` which does or does not bring in new commits.  Finally, we see if `HEAD` points to a new, different commit (`Y'`).  If so, the old SHA-1 and new SHA-1 will be different, the `!=` test will succeed, and we'll run the `git log`.

It's worth considering a few edge and error cases as well:

- What if there's no commit `Y`, i.e., your branch and the upstream branch are in sync?

  No problem!  Here `HEAD` will find commit `B` before the `pull`, and either find commit `B` again (no changes) or commit `C` (some changes).  The test will still do the right thing.
- What if the `pull --rebase` fails because the upstream can't be reached?

  This results in the same behavior as if there is no change in the upstream.
- What if the `pull --rebase` is able to fetch but the rebase fails?

  In this case, your commit (`Y`) is still your `HEAD` commit.  Here the script thinks nothing has changed and skips the `git log` ... but the `git pull --rebase` step printed some error(s) about the failed rebase, so that's probably the right thing.
- What if there's no `HEAD` revision?  (Empty repo; not in a git repo; other bizarre error.)

  In this case, `git rev-parse` will exit with an error, and `prev` will be set to the empty string.  The `git pull --rebase` step will also fail, and the second `git rev-parse` will fail again.  This is why I added the double quotes: now we will run `test "" != ""`.  Those two empty strings are equal and the script will skip the `git log` step.  So you'll get some extra error messages, but it will still work.

  (To make this more robust, we probably should stop the whole process if the first `git rev-parse HEAD` fails, but that's relatively minor.)

A more complicated (and interesting) method here is to find the actual upstream branch and see what happens do it in the `fetch` step.  This would allow you to log just what was done on the upstream branch, if anything.  It turns out that this is easy using the `@{u}` [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax:

```
old=$(git rev-parse @{u}) || exit # find current upstream, bail on error
git pull --rebase || exit         # update, bail on error
new=$(git rev-parse @{u}) || exit # find new upstream, bail on error
[ $old = $new ] && exit           # nothing to do if unchanged
ours=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit
if [ ! -z "$(git rev-list $new..$old)" ]; then
    # this is pretty rare; pull --rebase knows what to do though
    # could add "we rebased onto new head" if $ours != $new, perhaps
    echo "upstream removed old commits:"
    git log --oneline $new..$old
fi
if [ $ours != $new ]; then
    echo "upstream added new commits, which we rebased onto:"
else
    echo "upstream added new commits:"
fi
git log $old..$new
```

(note: script above is completely untested).